# rails active record specific id created between

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

i have a active record query that i attempted to make like this

```
@past_agents = User.joins(properties: { video: { theme: :clients } }).where(clients: { id: @client },created_at: (@starttime) .. @previous).uniq.count
```

i was told that this syntax is wrong so i changed it to

```
@past_agents = User.joins(properties: { video: { theme: :clients } }).where("clients.id = :client AND created_at >= :start_date AND created_at <= :end_date",{client: @client, start_date: @starttime, end_date: @previous} ).uniq.count
```

however its not working either. can someone tell me the proper way to do the query?

Comment: depends on what you want to do...
is it giving an error or just an empty result?

Comment: empty result, on my heroku postgres im doing the same query in sql format and getting a numerical result

Comment: executes the sql returned by  `User.joins(properties: { video: { theme: :clients } }).where("clients.id = :client AND created_at >= :start_date AND created_at <= :end_date",{client: @client, start_date: @starttime, end_date: @previous} ).uniq.to_sql` directly in the database and see if you get the records

Answer (score 1):

When you're dealing with a date range, the first way is my preferred way of writing it. See [Active Record Range Conditions](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#range-conditions).

By using the hash syntax, the resulting query will try to take advantage of the `BETWEEN` SQL statement. For example:

```
User.where(created_at: 6.months.ago..3.months.ago).to_sql
=> "SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\"  WHERE (\"users\".\"created_at\" BETWEEN '2015-02-05 01:04:47.710505' AND '2015-05-05 01:04:47.710616')"
```

Whereas, your second attempt does not:

```
User.where("created_at >= :start_date AND created_at <= :end_date", start_date: 6.months.ago, end_date: 3.months.ago).to_sql
=> "SELECT \"users\".* FROM \"users\"  WHERE (created_at >= '2015-02-05 01:07:26.998628' AND created_at <= '2015-05-05 01:07:26.998736')"
```

If you have a working SQL query already, I would suggest using [`to_sql`](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/to_sql) to determine the differences in the two queries. Hope that helps!